# Biased XGBoosting fot non target variable

Tags: probability, boosting, bias

I am training an XGBoosting model where the hyperparameter I got from `RandomizedsearchCV` and the best one was:

```
{'n_estimators': 800,
 'min_samples_split': 1500,
 'min_samples_leaf': 500,
 'max_features': 'sqrt',
 'max_depth': 17,
 'learning_rate': 0.1}
```

With this model I have an ER of 0.28
However when i use `predict_proba` and check for the distribution of both target and non target along the probabilities the results are:

On train

[image]

The distribution is OK for the target variable however for the 0 I hoped the same of the target variable but inverted (Decreasing amount of 0's as probabilities increased).

Is my model biased? What can I do?

Comment: I think it might be more useful to see how well calibrated the model is - as in, what fraction of the 0 - 10% probabilities are actually 1, what fraction of the 10-20% probabilities are actually 1, etc.   As it is, eyeballing it, it appears pretty well calibrated.  That's really what you want - when it says 50% probability, it actually is about a 50% probability.  (Of course, you would also prefer a U shape.)  Also, min_samples_leaf = 500 seems very high to me, as do min_samples_split and max_depth.  Gradient Boosting is about weak learners, after all...

Comment: How big is your sample, and how many features do you have?

Comment: That learning rate looks way too high for 800 estimators, also.

Comment: I didnt understando the first comment. 
The 1’s distribution looks fine to me. However I expected a decresing rate of 0 as the probability increased, when it is almost constant until the 60% probability. The sample is about 85000 for the train with 20 features (I have 40 features in total but i discarded half). What learning rate would you recommend? The model is not overfitting because almost the same plot is observed for the test part. Perhaps im missing something

Comment: Its a scorecard problem if it useful for sth

Comment: Also if we sum up each category it looks like the distribution of y_proba is biased to the right

Comment: What does "biased to the right" mean?

Comment: That most of the predictions are on the range 0.7-1. The models tends to give higher probabilities. Overstimating the probability of defaultt